# Take screenshots of specific areas

Tags: android, screenshot

What I am trying to achieve is that I would only want to screenshot specific areas using a view that can be dragged around the screen and whatever that the view is hovering on it will only screenshot whatever elements are within the dragged view.

I have been trying to search what to do or where to start, but my initial idea is to screenshot and then crop the image to get what I need.

But is there any other way other than `SCREENSHOT --> GET IMAGE --> CROP IMAGE`. Is it possible to just get a view and just capture what you need on the screen?

Comment: You need to draw a cropper frame over your View . Then get drawaingCache of whole view and cut the portion from it as at that time you will have the coordinates of your crop frame .

Answer (score 0):

```html
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(findViewById(R.id.activity_main),350,450);
        saveImage(bitmap);
    }
 
    public static void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/req_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        //  Log.i(TAG, "" + file);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 
    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey sir thanks for the answer, I have tried your code but unfortunately, I was unable to make it work. Nothing shows up.